# How to redirect urls from menu in php?

Tags: php

I have a menu like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contect</a></li>
    <li><a href="/references">References</a></li>
</ul>
```

And i would like to  tell that the / use home.php, the /contact get method use the contact.php and the /references use the references.php and of course th active class also change when we are at the contact menupoint and so on....
Thanks for the help! Im new with php sorr..

Comment: What you are looking for is called "url rewriting".

Comment: Look at htaccess and url rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it:

create a file with a name `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

if your files are under another folder like `includes/contact.php``

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/includes/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

getting your page via 'GET' in your `index.php`

```
$page = $_GET['page']; //contact.php
```

and test:

```
<a href="/contact"> Contact </a>
```